# devexpress mvc PageControl and PerformCallback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

Is it right or is it me, that the devexpress mvc PageControl **doesn't support** PerformCallback?

This declaration

```
  @Html.DevExpress().PageControl(
  settings =>
  {
  settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Profile", Action = "Content_Callback" };
  settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "function (s,e) { e.customArgs['currentUserId'] = $('#currentUserId').val(); }";

  settings.Name = "userProfilePageControl";
  settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
  ...
```

generates a Javascript **"userProfilePageControl.PerformCallback is not a function"** Error for

```
 function profileRefresh() {
        userProfilePageControl.PerformCallback();
    }
```

Everything else is fine, even the tab switch callback works fine...:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a method and there is no need to perform a callback programmatically.

Refer to the [Tab Strip - AJAX](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/TabControl/Callbacks)  online demo to learn more on how to load TabPages on demand (via callback)

Comment: The necessity to perform the callback programmatically results from the requirement to reload the whole tabstrip on changeing an external combobox. The on demand loading works fine, but after changeing the combox **all tabs need to be reloaded**... last resort a wrapping callback panel

Comment: Yes, in this case it is necessary to wrap the TabStrip with the CallbackPanel

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a SetActiveTab client side function?

[Client Side Functionality](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxNavigationAndLayoutDemos/TabControl/ClientSideAPI)